# Is structure (graph) of objects an Aggregate Root worthy of a Repository?

Tags: repository, domain-driven-design, entity

Philosophical DDD question here...

I've seen a lot of [Entity](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/109) vs. [Value Object](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/135) discussions here, but mine is slightly different.  Forgive me if this has been covered before.

I'm working in the financial domain at the moment.  We have funds (hedge variety).  Those funds often invest into other funds.  This results in a tree structure of sorts with one fund at the top anchoring it all together.

Obviously, a fund is an Entity ([Aggregate Root](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/88), even).  Things like trades and positions are most likely Value Objects.

My question is: Should the tree structure itself be considered an Aggregate Root?
Some thoughts:

- The tree structure is stored in the DB by storing the components and the posistions they have into each other.  We currently have no coded concept of the tree.  The domain is very weak.
- The tree structure has no "uniqueness" or identifier.
- There is logic needed in many places to "walk" the tree to find the relationships to each other, either top-down, or sometimes bottom-up.  This logic needs to be encapsulated somewhere.
- There is lots of logic to compute leverage, exposure, etc... and roll it up the tree.

Is it good enough to treat the Fund as a [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) Fund object and that is the Aggregate Root with in-built [Invariants](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/115)?  Or is a more formal tree structure useful in this case?

Comment: PS. I love composites. There's some really cool stuff you can do by creating static Expression<Func<TView, TEntity>> to provide flexible mappings to entity framework queries (which means massive reduction in the select size on your queries when you only need a list item). You can then also pass in 2 seperate lists from seperate repo's/services to composites expressions which makes having simple small repo's per entity extra worthwhile as you're rarely dealing with a whole entity tree... but that's a whole other story/post and very much a web technique.

Answer (score 2):

I usually take a more functional/domain approach to designing my aggregates and aggregate roots.

> This results in a tree structure of sorts

Maybe you can talk with your domain expert to see if that notion deserves to be a first-class citizen with a name of its own in the ubiquitous language (FundTree, FundComposition... ?)

Once that is done, making it an aggregate root will basically depend on whether you consider the entity to be one of the main entry points in the application, i.e. will you sometimes need a reference to a FundTree before even having any reference to a Fund, or if you can afford to obtain it only by traversal of a Fund.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a decision of if you want to load full trees at all times really.

If you are anal about what you define as an aggregate root, then you will find a lot of bloat as you will be loading full object trees any time you load them.

There is no one size fits all approach to this, but in my opinion, you should have your relationships all mapped to your aggregate roots where possible, but in some cases a part of that tree can be treated as an aggregate root when needed.

If you're in a web environment, this is a different decision to a desktop application.

In the web, you are starting again every page load so I tend to have a good MODEL to map the relationships and a repository for pretty much every entity (as I always need to save just a small part of something from some popup somewhere) and pull it together with services that are done per aggregate root. It makes the code predictable and stops those... "umm.... is this a root" moments or repositories that become unmanagable.

Then I will have mappers that can give me summary and/or listitem views of large trees as needed and when needed.

On a desktop app, you keep things in memory a lot more, so you will write less code by just working out what your aggregate roots are and loading them when you need them.

There is no right or wrong to this. I doubt you could build a big app of any sort without making compromises on what is considered an aggregate root and you'll always end up in a sitation where 2 roots end up joining each other somewhere.